# SQL Query IF exists then select the appropriate pk, else insert into

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Greetings dear people,

I'm trying to create a task list:
[tasklist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jTziW.png)

I'm using PHP and phpmyadmin with XAMPP.

Now I want that, if the CI (PC-Name) is entered, it searches it in the table "tblCI". If the CI was found in this table, the foreign key should be placed in another table and if it does not exist, the CI should be inserted into "tblCI".

I tried:

---

```
 $ci = [
        'ci' => $_POST['inputCI'],
        ];

 $sql1 = "INSERT INTO tblci (fldci) 
                VALUES (:ci) FROM DUAL 
                WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM `tblci` 
                WHERE :ci = :ci LIMIT 1)";
                $stmt1 = $connection->prepare($sql1);

if ($stmt->execute($data)<-- *this if for some other code* and $stmt1->execute($ci))
```

---

Does someone know how I should solve this?
Help is appreciated.
KR

PHPMYADMIN-Designer: [database_structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W8ueJ.png)

Comment: 1) Placeholders must be unique, so you can't use tree times `:ci`.  2) You can't use a placeholder for a column name, so even `:ci1 = :ci2` would fail.

Comment: Thanks for your answer: I had to change the query as follows: INSERT INTO tblci (fldci) 
                SELECT (:ci) WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tblci WHERE fldci = (:ci))"